# I want to select same column value as different columns name with different conditions from a single table in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT (SELECT EUDFD_VALUE FROM EMP_UDF_DATA WHERE EMPUDF_ID=10012) AS ADDRESS, 
       (SELECT EUDFD_VALUE FROM EMP_UDF_DATA WHERE EMPUDF_ID=10013) as CITY ,
       (SELECT EUDFD_VALUE FROM EMP_UDF_DATA WHERE EMPUDF_ID=10014) as Phone,
       (SELECT EUDFD_VALUE FROM EMP_UDF_DATA WHERE EMPUDF_ID=10015) as state,
       (SELECT EUDFD_VALUE FROM EMP_UDF_DATA WHERE EMPUDF_ID=10016) as Zip, 
       EMP_ID
FROM   EMP_UDF_DATA
```

I want to select the same column value as different column with the different conditions for multiple employees . I tried the above code but i could not solve it. Please help me to select the values. In the above code EUDFD_VALUE  is the column name which contains the address and phone number, city , zip, state. I want to display it separately for each employee using emp_id.

Comment: Please post minimal sample table and then desired output from this data

Comment: What's wrong with your query? Any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all those inner queries, you can do that with a mix of grouping and `case` expressions

```
select  EMP_ID,
        max(case when EMPUDF_ID=10012 then EUDFD_VALUE end) AS ADDRESS,
        max(case when EMPUDF_ID=10013 then EUDFD_VALUE end) as CITY,
        max(case when EMPUDF_ID=10014 then EUDFD_VALUE end) as Phone,
        max(case when EMPUDF_ID=10015 then EUDFD_VALUE end) as state,
        max(case when EMPUDF_ID=10016 then EUDFD_VALUE end) as Zip    
from    EMP_UDF_DATA 
group by EMP_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  EMP_ID,
        max(decode(EMPUDF_ID,10012,EUDFD_VALUE)) AS ADDRESS,
        max(decode(EMPUDF_ID,10013,EUDFD_VALUE)) as CITY,
        max(decode(EMPUDF_ID,10014,EUDFD_VALUE)) as Phone,
        max(decode(EMPUDF_ID,10015,EUDFD_VALUE)) as state,
        max(decode(EMPUDF_ID,10016,EUDFD_VALUE)) as Zip    
from    EMP_UDF_DATA 
group by EMP_ID
```